# Where do the malloc() block footer and header saved?

Tags: c, malloc

In generally spoken , in which device/table do  the `malloc()` block footer and header saved when   I use `void* malloc (size_t size)` ?

**Edit:**
I have `gcc (GCC) 4.8.1` compiler .

Comment: Depends on the implementation but most use the words before the malloc'ed block.

Comment: I'm afraid this is compiler/library-dependent, so please specify which compiler you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a typical implementation there's no "device" or "table". The header and the footer (if any) are integral parts of the block being allocated. The physically allocated block is larger than requested by the size of header and footer. So, what you actually allocate is

```
<header><user memory><footer>
```

The pointer returned by `malloc` points to the beginning of the `<user memory>` region.

I heard about implementations that stored the household information for `malloc` "elsewhere", but haven't seen them in real life.

Comment: `The header and the footer (if any) are integral parts of the block being allocated.` - so where that integral part details saved  ? I think it most be saved somewhere since `free(header)` using  , free all the range of `<header><user memory><footer>` .

Comment: `free(header)` is not valid (undefined behavior) because `header` was not returned by `malloc`.

Comment: @R.. : I mean `header` is the `void*` which returned by the `malloc()` .

Comment: No, it's not. In AndreyT's answer, the pointer returned by `malloc` points to `<user memory>`, and this is the only value you can legally pass to `free`.

Comment: @R.. OK , so how `free(<user memory>)` calling know where to stop "free-ing" ? probably it has any limit to stop somewhere   .

Comment: @URL87: It is all pretty straightforward. You do `free(<user memory>)`. The implementation of `free` steps back by the size of `<header>`, thus locating the beginning of `<header>`. And then it reads the size of the block from the `<header>`. That way it finds out how much to free.

Comment: The concept of "how much to free" is not really meaningful. The normal way an implementation of `free` works is to treat the memory as a unit and add it to a linked list of free memory that can be used to service future calls to `malloc`. This may involve merging it with adjacent free memory blocks to obtain a larger block.

Answer (score 1):

dlmalloc is the basis for a lot of newer malloc libraries. It is well documented. And most C programmers can read it easily, unlike some macro-studded, more modern, efficient, and portable  code.  It employs the memory just before the beginning of the user space for housekeeping.

Normally links are not supposed to be a good answer, but this is the link to the code --
http://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc-2.6.6.c

Comment: More modern and efficient? There's essentially no algorithm more modern or more efficient than dlmalloc. All of the improvements are basically just the same thing, but sometimes with per-thread bins (and possibly heaps) rather than a single set of bins; this allows you to avoid some locking and cache invalidation across cores at the expense of increased memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of variables that can be tuned to adapt the behavior of malloc() to the expected requirements and constraints of the application. Any changes to these tunables should be made before the very first call to malloc(). Note that some library functions might also use dynamic memory (notably those from the : Standard IO facilities), so make sure the changes will be done early enough in the startup sequence.

The variables __malloc_heap_start and __malloc_heap_end can be used to restrict the malloc() function to a certain memory region. These variables are statically initialized to point to __heap_start and __heap_end, respectively, where __heap_start is filled in by the linker to point, and __heap_end is set to 0 which makes malloc() assume the heap is below the stack.

If the heap is going to be moved to external RAM, __malloc_heap_end must be adjusted accordingly. This can either be done at run-time, by writing directly to this variable, or it can be done automatically at link-time, by adjusting the value of the symbol __heap_end.

The following example shows a linker command and the heap to location 0x1100 in external RAM. The heap will extend up to address 0xffff.

avr-gcc ... -Wl,--section-start,.data=0x801100,--defsym=__heap_end=0x80ffff ...

Comment: It looks like you've copied and pasted documentation from some particular embedded-system implementation which is not applicable in general.